# How to check If a html content fits in page of DOM Pdf or end of content

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I am working on patient reporting system and using **Dompdf** to print the reports. The report consist of header and In between them for eg Test report. I am having Issue with determining the end of the content as after that I have to put a statement saying end of report. I have attached two Images hope it makes my question clear.[image: The problem I am facing]

The problem I am facing.

And the normal flow of the pdf is as follows

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Share html and DOM pdf code ?

Comment: All you need to add is "end of report"? If so just use CSS with an `:after` block that defines your end-of-report text. It's a bit more difficult if your content is more complex, but that should be simple enough. I can post some sample HTML in an answer if this is the case.